# Woo-Commerce product options add

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to add product options in woo-commerce with radio button and image so user can easily navigate the product variations.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT****

This plugin seems to do what you require, you can add images as switches for the product variables (or alternativelycolor swatches

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-color-and-image-swatches/

---

You can use the standard woocommerce product variations to make product options that also correspond to different images, but the result is usually a dropdown.

You could potentially convert this dropdown to a radio using JS after pageload, but you can also use product add-ons plugin : https://woocommerce.com/products/product-add-ons/  to create radio options for products, but I'm not sure if this will allow dynamic image changing based on the options.

Comment: thanks but it may not work. and i want separate image from product image.  just like above given image.

Comment: This plugin allows images as buttons for changing product variable:
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-color-and-image-swatches/